# Coffeescript Classes not returning last statement of function

Tags: coffeescript

I have been using coffeescript classes, and as far as I was aware, functions should always return the last statement automatically. I am finding however, that functions defined in the constructor object, are not returning anything by default. Why is this?

### CoffeeScript

```
constructor: ->
  @ # <~~ returned as expected

class MyClass
  constructor: ->
    @ # <~~ not returned - why?

class MyClass
  constructor: ->
    return ->
      @ # <~~ returned like normal!
```

### JavaScript

```
var MyClass;

({
  constructor: function() {
    return this;
  }
});

MyClass = (function() {

  function MyClass() {
    this;

  }

  return MyClass;

})();

MyClass = (function() {

  function MyClass() {
    return function() {
      return this;
    };
  }

  return MyClass;

})();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "constructor" method is called when you use the "new" keyword on a class - therefore the return value is always supposed to be the new instance, not some other value that you'd like to return. However, it seems like CoffeeScripts lets you force a different return value via the "return" keyword.

```
class Foo
  constructor: -> {}

f = new Foo
f instanceof Foo   # expected to be very true...
```

When you name a normal function "constructor" (not a method = outside of a class definition), it's not a constructor but a regular function and therefore returns as expected.

Comment: I wonder if the "explicit return" is a bug in CoffeeScript (i.e. a side effect of normal function translation) or intentional. I can see someone adding "no implicit return in a ctor" logic but neglecting to add a "no explicit return value in a ctor" check. Just a [plain `return;`](http://coffeescript.org/#try:class%20C%0A%20%20%20%20constructor%3A%20(a)%20-%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%40a%20%3D%20'pancakes'%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20if(a%20%3D%3D%206)%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%40a%20%3D%20a%0A%0Aconsole.log(new%20C(6))%0Aconsole.log(new%20C(11))) does the right thing at least.

Comment: @muistooshort Good point. All I've found is this: https://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script/issues/1169#issuecomment-815764

Answer (score 2):

If you want to return a different object from a "constructor" method you
need to create a factory method as Coffeescript and Javascript do not
allow to overload the "new" operator

```
 class A
   @create: (params)-> new A params
   constructor: (params)-> console.log params

 a = A.create "foo"
```